# How do I secure rest api?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, security, oauth

I'm working an app with Angular.I want to get the data to be listed from rest api. However, I don't want users to access the resource. Which language, library or framework can I secure it with? And users are using the app without membership.

I tried jwt but I didn't get the result I wanted. Maybe I couldn't.

Here is express.js

```
const app = require('express')()
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({message: 'Rest API Work'})
})

app.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('data1.json','utf-8',(err,data)=>{
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        console.log(data)
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data,null,4))
    })
})



app.listen(3002, function(){
  console.log('Server OK')  
})
```

I want a simple security method where I can connect with Angular.

Comment: You can use JWT. https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-6-jwt-authentication

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary Here is the login / registration system. I don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to secure your API is start using a reverse proxy like Nginx. Javascript frameworks are all basically the same in terms of security. They all have a basic router handler, dispatcher (based of native Node.js HTTP library) and some basic helper methods, they give it a nice catchy name and that's it. I've checked the source code of almost all major frameworks. 
Now, some basic configuration params of Nginx are: `client_body_buffer_size` `proxy_buffers` etc. All your directives should regex input data too. Generally anything that could "filter" the malicious code is useful. Cloudflare can somehow help and some other companies that could secure your app but they're expensive.
Another good example is containerizing your app using Docker.
If you have a basic piece of code in Node.js, the most easy way to hack it is through your app's logic. You should use anti-XSS modules like `xss` or `express-sanitizer`. If you're using SQL database you should always escape the query values.

Answer (score 0):

## ASSUMPTIONS

> I'm working an app with Angular.

I am assuming that you are doing a Web App, and not a mobile app with something like NativeScript.

> I want to get the data to be listed from rest api. However, I don't want users to access the resource

I assume here that you want that only the web app to have access to the API, and not anyone else.

## LETS TACKLE YOUR QUESTIONS

> Which language, library or framework can I secure it with?

The problem is not the programming language or framework, but what you are trying to achieve, and I honestly have to tell you a cruel truth... In the context of the web is not possible to lock down an API to a Web app, and this is just because of the way the web was built, you know you hit F12 and you can see all the code running in the browser, therefore any secret you put there to identify your web app in each request it does to the API, will be up for grabs and reuse by anyone who wants to replicate your web app, and your API will not be able to distinguish the **WHO** is doing the request from **WHAT** is doing the request.

> And users are using the app without membership.

Contrary to what many developers may think, authenticated users don't lock-down a web app or mobile app to the API server, because the user is only one part of the equation, he represents the **WHO** is accessing the API, but you still need to address **WHAT** is accessing it.

Wait, wait a second... You keep referring to the **WHO** and the **WHAT**, do you care to explain it in more detail?

Glad you asked ;)

## The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

So let's clear a common misconception, among developers, about **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing an API server.

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing an API server, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

So replace the mobile app by web app, and keep following my analogy around this picture.

The Intended Communication Channel represents the web app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, communicating with the API server from the browser, not using Postman or using any other tool to perform a man in the middle(MitM) attack.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using Curl or a tool like Postman to perform the requests, a hacker using a MitM attack tool, like MitmProxy, to understand how the communication between the web app and the API server is being done in order to be able to replay the requests or even automate attacks against the API server. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the web app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the browser were your web app should be running from, with a real user.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the web app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise, you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users manipulating manually the requests or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the web app.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually is sent in the headers of the web app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the web app, inside obfuscated javascript, thus it becomes a runtime secret, that can be reverse engineered by deobusfaction tools, and by inspecting the traffic between the web app and API server with the F12 or MitM tools.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*. While in the context of a Mobile App, the overall idea is still valid in the context of a web app. You wish you can read the article in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

Now you may ask... If I can not lock down the API server to my web app only, how can I defend it?

## Defending an API Server

To start with a web app or even a mobile should only communicate with an API server that is under your control and any access to third part APIs services must be done by this same API server you control. This way you limit the attack surface to only one place, where you will employ as many layers of defense as what you are protecting is worth.

So anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you can learn more on [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques. While this articles are in the context of an API serving a mobile app, some of the content are applicable for an API serving a web app to, and will help you to understand how fragile an API is when it comes to distinguish from **WHO** and **WHAT** is accessing it. So this series of articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC and TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

Now that you are more aware of the pains of defending an API server, let's see what can be done to mitigate the security risks is facing in the context of a web app. For an API serving a web app, you can employ several layers of dense, starting with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about the detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All these solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that these solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at the same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

## CONCLUSION

> I want a simple security method where I can connect with Angular.

So as may have realized already, you are not able to achieve a simple security method to lock down your Angular app with the API server. That's it, a simple security method does not do the trick, and instead you need to resort to several solutions, that will reduce the attack surface, but will not eliminate it.

So In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.